why an image can be displayed on page but not as a favicon in link rel="icon" href=
I'm building a chrome extension to change the favicon of the newly opened tabs to differentiate them (to know that I did not read them yet), it works generally well except when CSP is applied. but a strange thing is happening:
I open for example a site using a strict CSP like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML
I use this code to load the dataURL image and assign the favicon to the page.
 rendered image
let FAVICON_URLl =  'data:image/png;base64,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';


// test1: load it in page
const imgg1 = document.createElement('img');
imgg1.src = FAVICON_URLl;
imgg1.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:0;border:2px solid black;width:80px;height:80px;z-index:99999;';
document.body.appendChild(imgg1);

// test2: load it as a favicon
const linkk = document.createElement('link');
linkk.type = 'image/png';
linkk.rel = 'icon';
linkk.href = FAVICON_URLl;
document.head.appendChild(linkk);

test1 gaves no error and the picture is displayed without any CSP error.
but test2 gaves this CSP error at document.head.appendChild(linkk);

Refused to load the image
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADA.....' because it
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src
'self' *.githubusercontent.com .googleusercontent.com .gravatar.com
mozillausercontent.com firefoxusercontent.com profile.stage.mozaws.net
profile.accounts.firefox.com mdn.dev
interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net
interactive-examples.mdn.allizom.net wikipedia.org
upload.wikimedia.org https://.google-analytics.com
https://.googletagmanager.com www.gstatic.com".

conclusion:
the image can be used and be displayed on the web page visually when we use it as img.src even if CSP block them, but cannot be used in head link rel tag <link rel="icon" href="...."> if CSP does not allow it.
here they say:

By default, browsers enforce the same-origin policy to prevent a web
page from accessing cross-origin resources. For example, when a
cross-origin image is loaded, even though it's displayed on the web
page visually, the JavaScript on the page doesn't have access to the
image's data. The resource provider can relax restrictions and allow
other websites to read the resource by opting-in with CORS.
https://web.dev/articles/security-headers

But what I do not understand is why in <link rel="icon" href= is not allowed, it is not javascript, and I'm not accessing it with javascript, so the browser should not block it because of CSP, it should be treated like img.src! no?
Why is this happening? I had read all what I could find about CSP but could not find anything that mentions this behavior. If this is expected, please do you have any source about this behavior? or an explanation at least?

Might be a bug. Note though that CSP isn't just about JS, it also applies to style/link/img elements. The note you've highlighted is about accessing the resource contents from JS e.g. via Canvas.

From the console on that page both the link and the img get rejected by CSP for me.

@Kaiido   maybe you need some permission, i do not remember if one is needed but here are some of my actual used ones that may help in that if it serves you:  "permissions": ["management", "tabs", "tabGroups"], and
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"], and
"web_accessible_resources": [{       "resources": ["_favicon/*"],       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],       "extension_ids": ["*"]     }],

@wOxxOm i just found this link https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40081966 , if i m not wrong it seems that it was working in the past then someone considered this a bug then chromium fixed it, so i don t think they will allow it ever. i think i have no choice except modifying the headers with declarativeNetRequest :(

It'd be still a bug because the report you've linked is about the native favicon and not about a resource added by an extension. Just to make sure, you don't use the MAIN world or run this code via a script DOM element?

@wOxxOm I use executeScript with world: 'ISOLATED' from a SW script. but if it is prohibited in the native page then extensions will not be able to change this fact because at the end the extension is changing the native favicon, no?

No, any resource added by a content script in the default (ISOLATED) world must be exempted from CSP of the page.

@wOxxOm true, i will fill a bug in chromium issues tracker, thank you for your help and guidance.
